# Issue with multiple map fragments overlapping

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have an application which has a main activity and several fragments which are navigated to via a navigation drawer.

I use two map fragments in my app, this seems to cause an issue if i go from fragment map A and then back to fragment map B . In frgamnet b i lose control of them map is generally just shows a snapshot of where fragmnet map A last was.

this seem to be a known issue see.

[google maps api bug report with issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5027&q=fragment&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal)

My solution as sugested on abouve fourm is to minimive map A before loading map B this causes the issue not to happen as it will not take up the screen space.

```
public void hideStupidMaps() {
    mMapView.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
    mMapView.getLayoutParams().width = 1;
    mMapView.invalidate();
    mMapView.requestLayout();

}
```

The above method is in my Gmap fragment class. i want to call it from myMain Activity class. in the navagation drawer code. My question is how do i call a frgments method from the main activity. especally when altering that fragment view. i need to inflate the view and it to the above method?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Managing) in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. A fragment must always be embedded in an activity and the fragment's lifecycle is directly affected by the host activity's lifecycle.

To return a layout from `onCreateView()`, you can inflate it from a layout resource defined in XML. To help you do so, `onCreateView()` provides a LayoutInflater object.

```
public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Here's how you can replace one fragment with another, and preserve the previous state in the back stack:

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```